# Setting default tab as visited

Tags: html, css

I have some basic tabs in HTML, with CSS to change the colour once the tab has been visited. My problem is that the default tab (that is selected when the page is opened) is not set as visited (as it hasn't been clicked yet). So when the user clicks a second tab, the default is marked as not visited yet.
Whats the easiest way for me to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the default tab a class to make the colour match the colour of a visited tab?

```
a.home_link
{
    color:#xxx;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying that and failing miserably, but you've put me in the right direction. I had attempted to create a class "visted" instead of "div.tab a.visited". Working now though, cheers.